# spring cloud gateway comprehensive documentation

Tags: spring-cloud

I don't find proper documentation fr the newly built spring cloud gateway. Could you please point me to the getting started guide? I am looking forward to build something like GraphDSL in Akka streams.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started with spring cloud gateway define following maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now create a simple routing(using path predicate) configuration in the application.yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
   gateway:
    routes:
    - id: test_route
      uri: https://stackoverflow.com/
      predicates:
      - Path=/testpath/
```

And the Gateway application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[Original reference tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway)

[Official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)